# "Hadoop-Solr Lucidworks Project" retrieve input name-path

Tags: hadoop, solr, lucidworks

I am using this project :https://github.com/lucidworks/hadoop-solr
Does anyone know in which value is saved the name (or the path) of the document that is being processed. I want to retrieve this value to Solr Admin (adding a field with its name to my schema). Is this possible?

Example:i want to able to see the name of the document, from which the query returns same results.

i am running the project with this command :

```
    hadoop jar solr-hadoop-job-2.2.5.jar 
    com.lucidworks.hadoop.ingest.IngestJob  
    -Dlww.commit.on.close=true -DcsvDelimiter= 
   -cls com.lucidworks.hadoop.ingest.CSVIngestMapper -c spyros1  
    - i  /usr/local/hadoop/input 
    -of com.lucidworks.hadoop.io.LWMapRedOutputFormat 
    -s http://127.0.1.1:8983/solr
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me :

```
hadoop jar solr-hadoop-job-2.2.5.jar com.lucidworks.hadoop.ingest.IngestJob  
    -Dlww.commit.on.close=true 
    -Dcom.lucidworks.hadoop.ingest.RegexIngestMapper.regex="\\w+" 
   -Dcom.lucidworks.hadoop.ingest.RegexIngestMapper.groups_to_fields=0=match_ss  
   -cls com.lucidworks.hadoop.ingest.RegexIngestMapper  
   -c collection1 -i /path/* -s http://127.0.1.1:8983/solr
   -of com.lucidworks.hadoop.io.LWMapRedOutputFormat
```

Also see [this](https://github.com/lucidworks/hadoop-solr/issues/16) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

For the `CSVIngestMapper` the file path is not currently added to any Solr field.

Feel free to create an issue in the repo. https://github.com/lucidworks/hadoop-solr

Also PRs are welcome

EDIT: (See https://github.com/lucidworks/hadoop-solr/issues/16 for the solution)

Comment: So is there any way to retrieve the name or the path of the document that result belong to? If i am using 2 txt documents how i am supposed to know from which txt the result came from. Is available for any other Ingest Mapper? @acesar

Comment: > Is available for any other Ingest Mapper?
yes, the RegexIngestMapper/GrokIngestMapper add a field called path. But I am not complete sure if I am following your use case.

Comment: I am using "data_driven_schema_configs" for my collection. The field must be added inside `managed-schema` of the data_driven_schema_configs  right? @acesar